# How to Fill a Form in Another Web Site, Submit the From and Retrieve Results with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dom, webforms, form-submit

As you may already get the idea from the question itself... What I want to achieve is: connect to a web site, fill out a form, submit the page and finally extract some information from the postback page that includes information regarding the data that I've submitted...
All af above should be handled programmatically in my site which will be coded with ASP.NET

**For e.g.
I want to connect to a booking web site. 
Pass the values like city, check-in date, check-out date and number of persons to stay.
Submit the page
And retrieve the descriptions of hotels and prices of rooms from result page** (I now this part requires dealing with the Dom Tree of target site and Regex)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).